# BIRT - Why I'm having error 500 : unable to load class for JSP?

Tags: swt, birt

My environment is :

- BIRT 3.7.1
- JRE 1.8.111 32 Bit
- Win 7 32 Bit

My environment variables are :

- JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
- Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;

I'm running BIRT in a SWT application.

Same reports are working on w2008 r2 64 Bit.

The error is :

```
HTTP ERROR 500 
Problem accessing/viewer/frameset. Reason : 
Org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
```

What can be wrong in my environment?

Comment: Chances are of JRE and eclipse installation mismatch. Meaning..for example, errors occur if you have a 32-bit Java environment 
and a 64-bit Eclipse installation or...that mismatch with BIRT plugin compatibility with 32 Bit or 64 bit

Comment: Everything is in 32 Bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed JDK instead of JRE. Seems working...